# PyQt5 focusIN/Out events

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using Python 3.4 and Qt 5 for the first time. It's easy and I can understand most of functionality which I need. But (there is always "but") I don't understand how to use `focusOut`/`clearFocus`/`focusIn` events.

Am I right that old way:

```
QObject.connect(self.someWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('focusOutEvent()'), self.myProcedure)
```

...does not work in Qt5?

I tried to understand [this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html) unsuccessfully. I'll be very thankful for a short example how to catch an event when e.g some of many `QLineEdit` has lost focus.

Comment: see my updated answer. I fell in the same trap as you expecting `focusInEvent` to be a signal when in fact it is an event handler. You have to subclass the object and override the function if you want to catch the event.

Comment: You may find the `editingFinished()` an acceptable alternative to catching loss of focus. It is triggered when the widget loses focus after an edit.

Comment: @mfitzp I came here because I had been expecting that to be so, but I have a QLineEdit, with a QDoubleValidator validator, where I can clear the text and move the focus away without raising the editingFinished signal, even though the text() method shows that the widget's value has become the empty string.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that `focusInEvent`/`clearFocus`/`focusOutEvent` are *not* signals, they are *event handlers*. See for example [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusInEvent). If you want to catch these events you will need to re-implement the event handler on your object, for example by subclassing QLineEdit.

```
class MyQLineEdit(QLineEdit):

    def focusInEvent(self, e):
        # Do something with the event here
        super(MyQLineEdit, self).focusInEvent(e) # Do the default action on the parent class QLineEdit
```

In PyQt5 the syntax for signals themselves is simpler. Taking for example the `textEdited` signal from QLineEdit, you can use that as follows:

```
self.someWidget.textEdited.connect( self.myProcedure )
```

This will connect the `textEdited` signal to your `self.myProcedure` method. The target method will need to accept the signal outputs, for example:

```
void    textEdited ( const QString & text )
```

So you could define your `self.myProcedure` in your class as follows and it will receive the `QString` sent by that signal.

```
def myProcedure(self, t):
    # Do something with the QString (text) object here
```

You can also define custom signals as follows:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal

class Foo(QObject):
    an_event = pyqtSignal()
    a_number = pyqtSignal(int)
```

In each of these cases `pyqtSignal` is used to define a property of the `Foo` class which you can connect to like any other signal. So for example to handle the above we could create:

```
def an_event_handler(self):
    # We receive nothing here

def a_number_handler(self, i):
    # We receive the int
```

You could then `connect()` and `emit()` the signals as follows:

```
self.an_event.connect( self.an_event_handler )
self.a_number.connect( self.a_number_handler )

self.an_event.emit()   # Send the signal and nothing else.
self.a_number.emit(1)  # Send the signal wih an int.
```

The link you posted gives [more information on custom signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html), signal naming and overloading with the new syntax.

Comment: The second half of your answer is a little confused: signals are not events, and they do not emit events. The signal-slot mechanism is essentially a callback system. The only time it interacts with the event loop is when the signal and slot are in different threads - in which case, the signal will be temporarily wrapped in an event and processed asynchronously. Otherwise, slots are always called directly (and synchronously). Signals and slots are how objects talk to each other. Events are more like a sensory system: how objects get to know about the outside world (e.g. mouse clicks).

Comment: @ekhumoro That's probably because I got halfway through writing before realising `focusInEvent` was not a signal. Will tidy it up, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to get this figured out so I thought I would post it here to help anyone else having this problem. It is in Python 3.9.6 and PyQt 6.1.2.

This changes the color of the widget when it is in focus and again when it is out of focus.

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Qt Testing")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 640, 120)

        h = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        w = ColorQLineEdit("one")
        h.addWidget(w)

        w = ColorQLineEdit("two")
        h.addWidget(w)

        self.setLayout(h)


class ColorQLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        print("in")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow; color: red;")
        super().focusInEvent(event)

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        print("out")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: black;")
        super().focusOutEvent(event)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Main()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Fixed the super in the focusOutEvent to call the proper super.