# how to get signal when field is activated (Python, PyQt5, QDateEdit)

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals, slots, qdateedit

I need to receive a signal when the field (QDateEdit) is activated. I did not find such a signal in the documentation.
Perhaps i need to redefine the class for this? but I don't know how to describe it all in working code

Comment: what do you mean activated?

Comment: Use ```QWidget::focusInEvent()```. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793440/pyqt5-focusin-out-events).